# Knockout dynamic view with coordinations

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of rectangles, each rectangle has coordination (x, y) and size (width, length). I need to build from this list a dynamic view that shows this rectangles at their size and place (of course this list can be change, so it's not hard-coded). Each rectangle has to be an HTML element (like DIV) because I need to insert text/images inside.
For example - [image]

I did it two years ago with canvas, but I want to know - **is there a way to create this view with KnockoutJS?**

Comment: This is certainly possible, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trevfu6k/).

Comment: Thanks!! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this is possible as long as you have the width, height, x and y coords available.

Have a look at the snippet below.

```js
var vm = {
  boxes: ko.observableArray([]),
  form: {
    width: ko.observable(250),
    height: ko.observable(250),
    x: ko.observable(250),
    y: ko.observable(250),
  },
  _addBox: function(width, height, x, y) {
    this.boxes.push({
      width: ko.observable(width),
      height: ko.observable(height),
      x: ko.observable(x),
      y: ko.observable(y),
    });
  }
}

vm.addBox = function() {
  this._addBox(this.form.width(), this.form.height(), this.form.x(), this.form.y())
}.bind(vm);


vm._addBox(100, 100, 0, 0);
vm._addBox(200, 100, 103, 50);
vm._addBox(200, 100, 306, 0);
vm._addBox(250, 100, 200, 153);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.container {
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.form {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.form label {
  display: block;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: boxes">
  <div class="box" data-bind="style: { width: width() + 'px', height: height() + 'px', left: x() + 'px', bottom: y() + 'px' }"></div>
</div>
<div class="form" data-bind="with: form">
  <label>Width
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: width" />
  </label>
  <label>Height
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: height" />
  </label>
  <label>X-coord
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: x" />
  </label>
  <label>Y-coord
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: y" />
  </label>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.addBox">Add Box</button>
</div>
```

You can take this snippet further and use the knockout [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) and/or the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) to dynamically add content to the boxes.